# Differential equation of the form $y'=Ay+b(x)$ with $b(x)=(\sin{(\omega x)},0)$

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations

I have a question regarding the following specific differential equation.

$$y'=\left(\begin{matrix}
        0 & 1 \\
        -1 & 0 \\
        \end{matrix}\right)y+\left(\begin{matrix}
    \sin{(\omega x)} \\
    0 \\ 
\end{matrix}\right) \;\; \textrm{with}\;\; y(x_{0})=y_{0}$$

I need to show that for every value of $\omega \neq \pm1$ there is at least one periodic solution for $y$. I have found that the solution to the equation is:

$$y(x)=\left(\begin{matrix}
\cos{x} & \sin{x} \\
-\sin{x} & \cos{x} \\
\end{matrix}\right)y_{0} + \int^{x}_{x_{0}}\left(\begin{matrix}
\cos{(x-\xi)}\sin{(\omega \xi}) \\
-\sin{(x-\xi)}\sin{(\omega \xi)} \\
\end{matrix}\right)d\xi$$

I have a hard time evaluating this integral, but I believe it should be possible to show that for every value $\omega \neq \pm1$ there is at least one periodic solution without evaluating the integral. I fail to see how any irrational number for $\omega$ should give a periodic solution.

Also how would one show that all solutions are periodic if and only if $\omega \in \mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: It seems odd to me that you have $x$ inside your integral whose limits are $x$.

Comment: I found the solution to the equation using the following equation, which is similar to the variation of constants.

$y(x)=\mathbf{\psi}(x)[\mathbf{\psi}(x_{0})]^{-1}y_{0}+\int^{x}_{x_{0}}\mathbf{\psi}(x)[\mathbf{\psi}(\xi)]^{-1}b(\xi)d\xi$ with $\psi$ the fundamental matrix.

Comment: @Jared For a more elementary approach to finding the solutions, see my answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/744296/differential-equations-diagonalizable-matrix/744324#744324). To get from the last formula in my answer to the one provided by the OP, just factor in the matrix exponential.

Comment: Isn't it the same question than http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/744922/solving-a-system-of-differentialequations-with-a-periodic-solution/746487#746487 ? If yes, I already gave my answer, thanks to Laplace transforms. Note that the integral exactly corresponds to the last term shown at end of my calculus.

Comment: @JJacquelin It is the same question yes. He is a class mate of mine. The answers in that post have helped me a lot, thanks!

Comment: There is no constraint on $\omega$ other than $\omega \neq \pm 1$.  It _always_ leads to periodic solutions.  You can get the general solution by solving the homogeneous part and then finding a particular solution using variation of parameters, you should get: $y_1 = A\cos(x) + B\sin(x) + \frac{\omega}{1 - \omega^2}\cos(\omega x)$ and $y_2 = B\cos(x) - A\sin(x) - \frac{1}{1 - \omega ^2}\sin(\omega x)$, where $\omega \neq \pm1$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\zeta =y_{1}+iy_{2}$ and $p=-i\partial _{x}$. Then

$$p\zeta (x)=-\zeta (x)-i\sin \omega x.$$

Next we note that
$$
(\exp [iap]f)(x)=f(x+a).
$$
Thus
$$
(\exp [iap]p\zeta )(x)=p\zeta (x+a)=-\zeta (x+a)-i\sin \omega (x+a)
$$
Assume $a=\frac{2\pi n}{\omega }$. Then
$$
\sin \omega (x+a)=\sin \omega (x+\frac{2\pi n}{\omega })=\sin \omega x,
$$
so $\zeta (x)$ and $\zeta (x+\frac{2\pi n}{\omega })$ satify the same
equation. In case there is a single solution then $\zeta (x)$ is periodic
with period $\frac{2\pi }{\omega }$. Assume that there are two solutions $%
\zeta _{1}(x)$ and $\zeta _{2}(x)$. Then their difference $\Delta \zeta (x)$
satisfies the homogeneous equation
$$
p\Delta \zeta (x)=-\Delta \zeta (x),\;\Delta \zeta (x_{0})=0,
$$
which only has the zero solution.